# Help In Generating Graph From Executing Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, excel, csv, graph

I am suppose to generate graph from the results/execution of my algorithm .  I have heard something about using CSV file in Excel and generating the graph. I have no idea what this CSV file is and how to do it. I googled CSV file but the answer i got was in connection with databases.

I am asking if someone can show me  or point me to a tutorial where this kind of thing has been done before. For instance i have to generate a graph from a Quicksort algorithm and also generate another graph with many algorithms at the same time.

Need help please

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSV == "comma separated values".  It's a file that has one row per line, where each value is separated by a comma.

I'm not sure how this is relevant to your algorithm or generating graphs.

Since you're using Java, you can easily generate a nice looking graph using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) from AT&T.  I think it's a terrific tool.